# Reload ViewController from AppDelegate after opening a Notification

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm currently trying to reload my ViewController after opening a Notification from the notification center. In my AppDelegate I'm using this function:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{

if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {

    //app is currently active, can update badges count here

}else if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground){


}else if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive){

    //CODE

    //REFRESH VIEW HERE, AFTER THE CODE ABOVE

}
```

}

How can this be done?
This is my first experience with Objective-C, so please don't be rude with me ihihihi.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `NSNotificationCenter` to let your `UIViewController` know you have some updated data to show.

In the `UIViewController` register to the notification center for your specific notification and then update your view.

In the app delegate:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
    postNotificationName:@"NEW_DATA_NOTIFICATION" 
    object:nil];
```

In your `UIViewController`, in the `viewDidLoad`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(receiveNewDataNotification:) 
    name:@"NEW_DATA_NOTIFICATION"
    object:nil];
```

Also in your `UIViewController`:

```
- (void) receiveNewDataNotification:(NSNotification *) notification {
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"NEW_DATA_NOTIFICATION"]) {
        NSLog(@"Received New Data Notification!");
        // Update your view here...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, do you have any hint or guide that I can follow?

Comment: @washedev I've added an example (very simple) to show you how it can be done with this kind of solution.

Comment: with this NSNotificationCenter can I still use my Notifications using pushwoosh? or is gonna overwrite it?

Comment: I don't know pushwoosh but I don't see why there would be some interference... Hope this will work...

Comment: You'll find all you need to know there: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotificationcenter